# Migrating to Webpack 4 from Webpack 3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, gulp, webpack-4

I am trying to migrate to Webpack 4, but is has been a real pain. After couple of days working on moving Webpack 3 plugins to Webpack 4 native stuff, I got the `js` to be rendered fine supposedly, but when I go to my website I got this message on the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value).push is not a function`

On:

`(window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || []).push([["Index"],{`

This is my Webpack `output` settings:

```
output: {
    filename,
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'build', 'js'),
    jsonpFunction: 'webpackJsonp', // TODO gotta figure that out
},
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us your whole webpack file?

Comment: I wrote an article on setting up webpack 4, I hope it helps https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-conquer-webpack-4-and-build-a-sweet-react-app-236d721e6745

Comment: why do you need a non-default jsonpFunction?

Answer (score 14):

Just had the same issue and I have found this thread https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6985

It seems to happen when you have modules bundled with *Webpack* < 4. I'm posting it here if it can be of any help.

Changing the `output.jsonpFunction` https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-jsonpfunction to `jsonpFunction` solved it:

```
{
  output: {
    jsonpFunction: 'jsonpFunction',
    ...
  }
}
```

Credit goes to goes to @sokra (the creator of Webpack): https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6985#issuecomment-380795070

Comment: BTW I had the issue while code-splitting with React-Loadable

Comment: Thanks a lot to this answer. I've been banging my head trying to figure out the solution. I had the same issue with two builds on same page. one project was old using webpack 3, other one was new.

Comment: Glad it helped, it's a pretty difficult issue to debug